# Search in Column Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a column in Powerbi with postal code and City in the same cell.
I would like to have Zipcode in a column alone.

My problem is that the length of postal code varies from country to country.

Some have 5 characters others have 4  ex. *7400 Herning*, *12307 Berlin*

The postal code and city are separated with a "space".

Is it possible to have a code that return all characters that returns everything until the first "space"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `Column From Examples` in Power Query

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, a feature i wasn't aware of. :-)

Comment: Alternately Text.Split([Column]," "){0}

Comment: The advantage of `column from Examples` is irrespective of position of postal code, they will be get extracted

Answer (score 0):

1. Split Column by Delimiter

[image]

[image]

2. Split Column by Digit to Non-Digit

[image]